# Nightwatch Unable to locate element using xpath

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am new to Nightwatch and trying to write a simple test. I am getting the following error.

```
ERROR: Unable to locate element: "//label[data-id="CC"]" using: xpath

    let suite = {
  "Test 1.": function (client) {
    client.useXpath();
    page = client.page.configure.deviceProperties.default();
    page.navigate(); 
    page.waitForLoader();
  }, 

  "column selector": function(client){

    page
    .verify.containsText('//label[data-id="CC"]', 'CC')

    client.pause(100);
  }
```

I also have tried with

```
'label[data-id="CC"]'
'label[@data-id="CC"]'
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

-dj

Comment: Did you check whether that selector works in the console, e.g. go to that page, open up the javascript console and paste in the xpath with $x('//label[data-id="CC"]') and hit return? Did you get the element you expected?

Answer (score 0):

the attribute must contains prefix @ using xpath (as you have specified)
like "//label[@data-id='CC']" which should works
and in CSS it looks like "label[data-id='CC']"

add a waiting step before test like waitForElement

[using xpath]

```
page.waitForElementVisible("//label[@data-id='CC']", 2000, false, function(result){
  if (result.status === 0) {
     page.verify.containsText("//label[@data-id='CC']", 'CC')
  }
});
```

or expect :

```
page.expect.element("//label[@data-id='CC']").text.to.contain('CC').before(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `('//label[@data-id="CC"]', 'CC')`, and you should try your xpath in the browser console to test whether the xpath is correct or not.